# Why am I getting "Warning: mysql_close(): supplied argument is not a valid MySQL-Link resource" on this line?

Tags: php, mysql

**PSA:** do not use mysql_ functions. See an explanation below in the answers.

I have a `mysql.php` file with a class named `dbAccess` which handles my insert queries. I didn't have any issues with this file until today, and I'm not sure if I accidentally changed something or what.

The warning is:

> Warning: mysql_close(): supplied argument is not a valid MySQL-Link
>   resource in /home/www/data/dbAccess/mysql.php on line 83

line 83 is this:

```
mysql_close($this->dbserver);
```

`dbserver` defined as `private $dbserver;`. the server is set with

```
$this->dbserver = "my.server.address.com"
```

Don't really know what I'm doing wrong with this one... Like I said it was working fine until today so I must of accidentally hit something in one of my other files which use the class? pointers on where to look are much appreciated.

Comment: Please. [Do not use `mysql_` functions in PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php).

Comment: The string "my.server.address.com"  is not a valid MySQL-Link resource, is it?

Comment: There are many many results when Googling `"Warning: mysql_close(): supplied argument is not a valid MySQL-Link resource"` Pick one. Probably an "out of scope" issue.

Comment: @JakeGould I don't agree with you here. Other people might see this question and not know about `mysql_` being deprecated. I see you have edited my answer, but I've added a (smaller) warning at the bottom of my answer.

Comment: @JakeGould I'm not upset about it and I certainly wasn't trying to lecture people - and I apologize if I made that impression. I was simply trying to warn whoever would read that answer, because there are still far too many people who don't seem to know that using `mysql_` functions isn't a very good idea anymore. That's all ;)

Comment: Take it outside boys. Anyone is entitled to signal the deprecation of the `mysql_` function; let's just leave it at that, shall we?

Comment: No worries gentlemen :) I appreciated both your input. Thanks for the help! Now to figure out this bloody `Unable to jump to row 0 on MySQL result index..` issue... :|

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`mysql_close()`](http://www.php.net/mysql_close) accepts a connection resource as parameter - you're passing a string (`my.server.address.com`).

The resource is returned by `mysql_connect()`. You probably have something like this in your code:

```
$connection = mysql_connect(...);
```

Simply use pass this variable to `mysql_close()`:

```
mysql_close($connection);
```

If you didn't store the connection in a variable, you can call `mysql_close()` without parameters as well.

> "If `link_identifier` isn't specified, the last opened link is used."

It's not even necessary to use `mysql_close()`, because open connections are closed automatically at the end of the script's execution.

See http://www.php.net/mysql_close for more information.

**Attention:** For other people that are reading this answer: please note that [`mysql_` functions are deprecated](http://www.php.net/manual/en/intro.mysql.php).

Comment: For whatever reason, the connection was never associated with a variable. It's just `mysql_connect($this->dbserver,$this->username,$this->password);   
   mysql_select_db($this->dbname);`

Comment: And yes for the record -- listen to everyone here fellow coders, never use mysql_. I've learned my lesson :)

Comment: Well that's not a problem either. It's an optional argument, you can call `mysql_close()` without any parameters as well. You can even omit `mysql_close()` completely - see http://www.php.net/mysql_close